# Slack Web API | User Bot Builder Payload

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit

There is a slack Web API to post a message to slack.

```
chat.postMessage
```

This works completely fine with normal text. Wanted to check if we can use the Bot Kit Builder JSON payload with Web API to post rich cards via Slack Web API as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, Nevermind, I did not went through the entire documentation of API. we can use "blocks" parameter and paste bot builder payload there.